# Makefile? make doesn't have any commands at all?

Tags: makefile, vagrant, putty

Soo i have some problems with make.

Im using PuTTY where i have used Sudo apt-get install make.
then it installed make. but when i try to use any commands like      *make all* or     *make* all i get is

```
        ***make:   *** No rule to make target 'all'.   stop***
```

Thats then i type     *make all*   I have even downloaded the newest ¨make¨ thingie here http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/ but i just can't get it to work so please anyone help me.

Comment: `make all` won't work unless your makefile contains an `all` target...

Comment: but it didn't create a makefile when i installed it, and i have removed it and installed it agian? soo how do i get a makefile?

Comment: I think you may need to read up on what Make actually is.  It doesn't *create* makefiles; *you* write a makefile, and then Make runs it.

Comment: `make` wont install any `Makefile`, your project should have it's `Makefile`, and `make` will just run it. If no `Makefile` is present there is nothing for `make` to do.

Comment: I think you should try reading some documentation.  For example: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overview.html and then proceed from there.  You can't just pick up a complex tool like make and expect to be able to use it without spending any time reading any documentation, then waste everyone _else's_ time on a site like StackOverflow trying to explain it to you.  SO is not a tutorial or online university.  If you read the docs and can't figure something specific out, THEN come ask about that something on StackOverflow, and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a Makefile, there is nothing for Make to do.

Make is sort of a programming language; by itself, without a "program" you write, it doesn't do anything at all.

Note that Make requires literal tabs before any shell commands.

Here is a simple minimal Makefile to get you started.

```
.PHONY: all
all:
        echo commands
        cp Makefile Makefile.copy
```

The .PHONY pseudotarget marks `all` as not a file (i.e. Make will perform the recipe even if an up-to-date file named `all` already exists).

More realistically, you would write the above example in two steps; declare that `all` depends on `Makefile.copy`, and separately declare how to create this file if it is out of date;

```
.PHONY: all
all: Makefile.copy
        echo commands

Makefile.copy: Makefile
        cp $< $@
```

If you run `make` twice, you will see that Make notices that `Makefile.copy` already exists, and is newer than the files it depends on, so Make will not run the recipe to create it.

Comment: but it didn't create a makefile when i installed it, and i have removed it and installed it agian? so help me! how do i get the makefile!?

Comment: @user3245348: I don't think you get `make`'s general idea. It is not supposed to create Makefiles, it's job is only to interpret them.

Comment: It was meant to the OP.

Comment: okay thanks. so i just type that in and make it to a file called makefile? and were do i save it to?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you save as `Makefile` it would seem obvious what the file name is? Anyway, what you put in the Makefile depends entirely on what you want to accomplish. Maybe post a separate question where you explain your actual goal. See also [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).